# Find and list all polygons that overlap with another polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, analysis, overlapping-features

I am working with two polygon layers which overlap but are unrelated (one is congressional district boundaries, the other is MPO area boundaries).

I would like to generate a list of all the polygons in one layer which overlap with each polygon in the second layer.  I.e. I want to generate a list of all the Congressional districts which are at least partially within each MPO area.

Which vector tools or plugins can I use to get there?

I'm using QGIS 1.8 on OSX 10.6.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the intersect tool in the Vector menu under Geoprocessing Tools. You select the two layers you are interested and an output location. This will create a new shapefile with the attributes of the overlapping features. In the attributes you should then have the MPO and Congressional District numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use spatial database (Spatialite for example) and SQL-querry for it. I suppose you know that QGIS is able to work with databases and run queries. Also there is a  [Spatialite-GUI](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index) that allow to add virtual shp-files to the database so you don't actually need to import your data into the database. Now if you need to get "ID" field from `layer1` for objects that intersects with objects from `layer2` use simple querry (assume that Geometry is the field where geometry is stored):

```
SELECT ID
FROM layer1 
WHERE  (SELECT ST_Intersects(layer1.Geometry, layer2.Geometry))
```

Notice that no additional (unwanted) layers will be created here.